# Access column name by value in a cell C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm writing a code to read an Excel file and filter the data based on 2 columns. 1 column is fixed and the other one is changed monthly. My attempt is to capture the column name of the dynamic column (which is changing Monthly) by value of one of its cell. is this possible? my ultimate goal is to perform the following code. (where you need the column names)

```
 DataTable ObjFilteredTable = objDataView.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2");
```

Thanks

I have seen lot of sample where you get the cell value based on the column name. I need it other way around.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the column index instead... How do you get the excel data into your c#? what type is objDataView?

Comment: I used IExcelDataReader to get the data to a DataTable. and  objDataView is a DataView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could do the trick:

```
    static string GetMyColumnName(DataView objDataView, object YOURVALUE)
    {
        int colCount = objDataView.Table.Columns.Count;
        foreach (DataRowView rowView in objDataView)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                if (rowView[i] == YOURVALUE) // Check if cell value is the one you are looking for
                    return objDataView.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        }
        throw new Exception("Column not found");
    }
```

YOURVALUE is the value you talk about when you say: "My attempt is to capture the column name of the dynamic column by value of one of its cell"

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpler way to do this is,to access the column by its index.

Try this.

1.Read the complete Excel row to a Data Table.

2.Get the dynamic column name by its index.